# Qt6 Android service with separate ".so" library and CMake

Tags: android, cmake, qt6

I have Qt 6.3 CMake-project that contains two subdirectories "app" and "service", i want include Android service .so library into result APK.
With qmake-project i can achieve this like that at app.pri:

```
contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, arm64-v8a) {
  release: ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = $$OUT_PWD/../service/libservice_arm64-v8a.so
  debug: ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = $$OUT_PWD/../service/libservice_arm64-v8a.so
}
```

with CMake i tried to `set(QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS C:/workspace/build-test-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/service/libservice_arm64-v8a.so)`
at app->CMakeLists.txt and it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS is 'target property' and should be set via set_target_properties() then it adds .so into result.

```
set_target_properties(project_name  PROPERTIES 
QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../service/libservice_${ANDROID_ABI}.so)
```

Comment: where is your final code? how did you this in your code?

Comment: @mohsen added code to answer

Comment: I added your solution but it doesn't work, I decompile apk but it doesn't containt *so file.

Comment: @Zappy.Mans it works, does your build subdirectory for service (e.g build-projectname-Android_Qt_6_4_2_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/service/) contains libservice_arm64-v8a.so?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I had the same problem recently, and I think I found the answer in the qt official documentation, which I posted a link to:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-target-property-qt-android-extra-libs.html

Here's how I used it, and it worked:

```
qt_add_library(protobuf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/depends/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.so)
add_dependencies(${APP_NAME} protobuf)
```

Comment: yes, they added it recently to documentation (in 6.4.x/6.5.x)